# Jquery animated conent change?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I want to change the Content in a div with a animation or a fade or something ?

Is this possible ?

I load the Content over a Ajax Post request into a div.

```
function getPage(id) {

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "./ajax/engine.php",
        data:'action='+id+"&userkey="+mykey,
        type: "POST",
        success:function(data){

        }
    });
}
```

At the Moment its like Booom there is the content when i click on a Navbar Point.

Thanks for all Ideas!

Comment: What is `</center>');`

Comment: A Mistake of the Stackoverflow Editor! :D

Comment: Then what is `);` after `slideToggle`, your mistake?

Comment: Yes, Chaos after deleting and editing the Code Part after pasting. 
I edited now correct.

Comment: So what's the problem with `.show()` ?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to show and hide a div with some effect. you can use this code:

```
function getPage(id) {
    jQuery(id).hide('fast');
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "./ajax/engine.php",
        data:'action='+id+"&userkey="+mykey,
        type: "POST",
        success:function(data){
           jQuery(id).html(data).show('slow');
        }
    });
}
```

I ref you to [.show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/) and [.hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) function. Jquery do some animation by itself and have many function for that. You can use [.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) and [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) too. but for your case, use `show()` and `hide()`